# How can I avoid reads for documents that I'm not interested in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of 2k documents. I have implemented pagination so I can get 10 docs at a time. A document looks like this:

```
docId
  - name: "itemName"
  - price: 20
  - lastModified: May 22, 2020 at 1:23:22 PM UTC
```

To get the first 10 elements I use this query:

```
Query query = db.collection("items").orderBy("name", ASCENDING).limit(10);
```

To get the next 10 documents, I use:

```
Query nextQuery = query.startAfter(lastVisibleDocumentSnapshot);
```

First time I open the app I scroll 3 pages, so a total of 30 docs will be added to the cache. Second time I open the app, I don't want the documents to be downloaded again. Since I have that `lastModified` field, I can query:

```
db.collection("items").whereGreaterThan("lastModified", someDate);
```

This it will return all new/modified docs, which is bad because if 200 docs were added, I pay for them. In other words, I pay 200 reads for documents that I might not be interested in. How can I manage to pay a read operation only if one of those 30 documents is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do isn't possible with your data. You can't have a query that's ordered by a different field than your range query.  So, if you have a range query on `lastModified`, then you can't also order by `name`.  And you if you order by `name`, you can't use a range filter by `lastModified`.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say I don't need that order, how about that? My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933031/how-to-read-data-only-from-cache-in-firestore). Hope you get the idea better now.

Comment: Then just query with lastModified?  You can't query both cache and server at the same time.  It's either/or.

Comment: Yes Doug, that's the problem. When I open the app second time, I don't want to be charged again for those 30 elements. I want to be charged only if one of the elements is changed. If none of them is changed, I only need to get the data from cache. Seems that van Puffelen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933031/how-to-read-data-only-from-cache-in-firestore) doesn't help anymore :(

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible in this case.